# my minecraft game directory isnt correct

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

when I load up my minecraft it shows the updates but when I press play it does the blue bar and then it says launching. and it stays like that. so I left my launcher up since before I ate lunch(that was at 2:38) and it is still like that. I have the newest launcher and minecraft 1.8.1.

Comment: Is there anything in the console output to indicate what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I found out! you click the start button then type run in the search thing then click the first one and type in "%AppData%.minecraft then click ok find launcher pack (there might be two so try both) it should bring you to a window that has launcher.pack right click it then find copy to... double click it and copy it over (you may have to type it).

Comment: Sometimes when an update is applied/you upgrade to a new launcher, Minecraft will create a new directory. It's not normal, sure, but it's not unheard of :)